# Is my Object returning a hidden 'null' value?

Tags: javascript

My code seems to return a null value that isn't explicitly declared in the object.

What I'm trying to program is a code that will go through an array of objects, find which value is null, then add a 'question' key to equal to "Hi, could you please provide your 'key'. " Finally I would like to return the array of objects with the question key.

Please see the code below:

```
var list1 = [
  { firstName: null, lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java' },
  { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 35, language: null },
  { firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', continent: 'Americas', age: 32, language: 'Ruby' } 
];

function askForMissingDetails(list) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      for (var prop in list[i]) {
        if ( list[i].prop == null) 
          list[i]['question'] = `Hi, could you please provide your ${prop}.`;
        else 
          list.splice(i,1);
      }
    }
  return list;
}

console.log(askForMissingDetails(list1))
```

The output I get is :

```
[
0:  {
firstName:  null
lastName:   "I."
country:    "Argentina"
continent:  "Americas"
age:    35
language:   "Java"
question:   "Hi, could you please provide your question."
}
1:  {
firstName:  "Lukas"
lastName:   "X."
country:    "Croatia"
continent:  "Europe"
age:    35
language:   null
question:   "Hi, could you please provide your question."
}
2:  {
firstName:  "Madison"
lastName:   "U."
country:    "United States"
continent:  "Americas"
age:    32
language:   "Ruby"
question:   "Hi, could you please provide your language."
}]
```

Comment: You probably want `list[i][prop]` instead of `list[i].prop`. You're also potentially modifying `list` while iterating it so that's going to have side effects

Comment: What happens if more than one value is `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing ways to access objects. Firstly, you're reading `list[i].prop`. This will look for a property quite literally called `prop`. To fix this, change that to `list[i][prop]`. The square brackets in this case represent *dynamic lookup*. Rather than looking for the `prop` key, you are looking for the key that is the *value of `prop`*.

Answer (score 1):

I using reduce to create a new list with the property question to keep in array if have multiple null values in your objects:

```js
var list1 = [
  {
    firstName: null,
    lastName: "I.",
    country: "Argentina",
    continent: "Americas",
    age: 35,
    language: "Java"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Lukas",
    lastName: "X.",
    country: "Croatia",
    continent: "Europe",
    age: 35,
    language: null
  },
  {
    firstName: "Madison",
    lastName: "U.",
    country: "United States",
    continent: "Americas",
    age: 32,
    language: "Ruby"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Christian",
    lastName: null,
    country: "Perú",
    continent: null,
    age: 32,
    language: null
  }
];

// using list1 as context to apply reduce to be saved on myNewList
const myNewList = list1.reduce((acc, item) => {
  // itering keys names of the current object
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    // if the current key name his value is null
    if (!item[key]) {
      // if haven't a key name called question, i create it as a new empty array
      if (!item.question) item.question = [];
      // pushing into the array the message with the current key name(because is null) 
      item.question.push(`Hi, could you please provide your ${key}.`);
    }
  });
  // pushing into the accumulator the current object
  if (item.question) acc.push(item);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(myNewList);
```

Comment: This is very thorough but OP states they want to omit the _complete_ items from the final array

Comment: @Phil, oh sorry... i didn't read completely, mmm just should add one if on acc.push(item).

Comment: not exactly what I wanted, but a good example of reduce that I can go through. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = list1.reduce((acc, list) => {
    let missedKey = "";
    for(let key in list){
        if(!list[key]) missedKey = key
    }
    if(missedKey) { 
        list.question = `Hi, could you please provide your ${missedKey}.` 
        acc.push(list)
    };
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you're after is a *map / reduce* operation.

You want to alter your original array to include questions where there are `null` values (*"map"*) and filter out the entries that are complete (*"reduce"*).

This can all be accomplished using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const list = [{"firstName":null,"lastName":"I.","country":"Argentina","continent":"Americas","age":35,"language":"Java"},{"firstName":"Lukas","lastName":"X.","country":"Croatia","continent":"Europe","age":35,"language":null},{"firstName":"Madison","lastName":"U.","country":"United States","continent":"Americas","age":32,"language":"Ruby"}]

const missingDetail = list.reduce((arr, item) => {
  // find first null value entry
  let [ missing ] = Object.entries(item).find(([ prop, val ]) => val === null) || []
  if (missing) {
    // missing contains the property name of the first null value
    // push new item-with-question object to the final array
    arr.push({
      ...item,
      question: `Hi, could you please provide your ${missing}`
    })
  }
  return arr
}, [])

console.info(missingDetail)
```